# logging to syslog file with Zerolog (GoLang)

Tags: go, logging

I just started writing my first project in GoLang. I want to send logs to syslog(*/var/log/syslog*) file.

I am using **zerolog**(*github.com/rs/zerolog*) package to write logs.
This is my how I am logging currently:

```
log.Error().Str("Event_name", Event_name).Msg("Invalid event")
```

It is printing logs to terminal but not to syslog file. Can someone give example or explain how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send entries to syslog with zerolog, locally and remotely with and without TLS, using the code below.

I previously mentioned *I was not able to get the Levels working as I expected them to, and all the remote logs showed up as `KERN` level logs in my Synology NAS Log Center.*, turns out I was looking in the `Category` column because the `Level` column was collapsed. The Levels are working as expected.

The standard library syslog package does not provide TLS support, hence using the now archived srslog by RackSec.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log/syslog"

    "github.com/RackSec/srslog"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
)

func main() {
    // remote syslog over unencrypted tcp
    var zsyslog zerolog.SyslogWriter
    zsyslog, err := syslog.Dial("tcp", "192.168.0.44:514", syslog.LOG_KERN|syslog.LOG_EMERG|syslog.LOG_ERR|syslog.LOG_INFO|syslog.LOG_CRIT|syslog.LOG_WARNING|syslog.LOG_NOTICE|syslog.LOG_DEBUG, "stackOverflow")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    zsyslog.Debug("Debug message 1")

    zog := zerolog.New(zsyslog).With().Caller().Logger()
    zog.Debug().Msg("Debug message 2")

    //local syslog of unix sockets
    zsyslog2, err := syslog.New(syslog.LOG_KERN|syslog.LOG_EMERG|syslog.LOG_ERR|syslog.LOG_INFO|syslog.LOG_CRIT|syslog.LOG_WARNING|syslog.LOG_NOTICE|syslog.LOG_DEBUG, "stackOverflow")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    zsyslog2.Debug("Debug message 3")

    zog2 := zerolog.New(zsyslog2).With().Caller().Logger()
    zog2.Debug().Msg("Debug message 4")

    // remote syslog over tcp+tls (encrypted)
    useTLS := false
    if useTLS {
        certPath := "/path/to/cert.pem"
        zsyslog3, err := srslog.DialWithTLSCertPath("tcp+tls", "192.168.0.44:514", srslog.LOG_KERN|srslog.LOG_EMERG|srslog.LOG_ERR|srslog.LOG_INFO|srslog.LOG_CRIT|srslog.LOG_WARNING|srslog.LOG_NOTICE|srslog.LOG_DEBUG, "stackOverflow", certPath)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        zsyslog3.Debug("Debug message 5")

        zog3 := zerolog.New(zsyslog3).With().Caller().Logger()
        zog3.Debug().Msg("Debug message 6")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should open the file /var/log/syslog and then set the output of your logger to that file:

```
output, err := os.OpenFile("/var/log/syslog", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
if err != nil {
    // unhandled error
}

log.Error().Str("Event_name", Event_name).Msg("Invalid event")

log.Output(output)
```

By the way, you must have sudo privileges when reading/writing system files. this means that your executable must be run under sudo

Comment: Wouldn't Opening a file and writing to that would be too inefficient for performance? I saw that some syslog hooks can do it efficiently(like in default go logger).

Comment: then why not to use log/syslog package?: logger, err := syslog.NewLogger(syslog.LOG_INFO, 0)

Comment: log/syslog doesn't provide level logging, right?

Comment: Never, ever, write to /var/log/syslog. When "syslog" is referred to, it is always implied that logging is sent to a syslog daemon. The syslog daemon in turn will be the one that writes to /var/log/syslog, as well as forwarding logs via other channels.